# is it possible to hide textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a text box and I want to hide the text box value when I entered a particular value in the text box.

For Eg:- when I type -1 then the value should hide in the text box but it should exist in the ng-model.

How can I achieve this functionality.

```
 <input type="text" id ='xyz' ng-model="model"/>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bdmqxr5y/746/)

Comment: can you describe what do you mean by "hide". What should happen when you try to change it from `-1` to something else?

Comment: it could be enough to check if the value is negative with `ng-change="check()"` and simply change CSS (to a white coloured text) with `ng-class`/`ng-style`

Comment: when I type -1 then the value should be hidden in the text box, but when I type other than -1 then it should contain the entered value

Comment: @AlekseySolovey can you please provide some sample code related to that solution

Comment: But having already entered -1 and having it hidden, can a user then edit that value? What if they're trying to enter -11?

Comment: @@Some ideas:

# Make the textcolor the same as the background color.
# Use the onKeyPress event, after every keystroke take the value from this box, and append it into a hidden textbox you've got elsewhere on the page (or a javascript variable.

Comment: @nnnnnn actually in that text field minus(-) is restricted and user cannot enter minus there, data will come from backend. and user can edit the value

Comment: Please discuss the requirement with your team. really confusing how a hidden input user can Edit. Above all why to hide the input text. Just use password type.

Comment: Your question says "when I type -1", but now you're saying in comments that the user can't actually type that at all, it could only have that value if populated from the backend? That would've been nice to know earlier. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to describe the requirements in more detail.

Comment: @user9130953 I have two solution in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48640396/8495123) that work slightly differently but ultimately hide your values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Try this for hind `-1`

```js
angular.module("test",[]).controller("testc",function($scope) {
 
 $scope.hideValue = function(value) {   
  if (value) {
   $scope.realModel = value.toString().replace("-1","");
  }
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testc">
<input type="text" id ='xyz' ng-model="realModel" ng-change="hideValue(realModel)"/>

</div>
```

---

### if you want remove negative value then please try this

```js
angular.module("test",[]).controller("testc",function($scope) {

$scope.hideValue=function(value) {   
  if (value) {
    var text =  value.substr(value.length - 2);
    if(parseInt(text) <= 0) {
      $scope.realModel = value.toString().replace(text.toString(),"");
    }
  }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testc">
<input type="text" id ='xyz' ng-model="realModel" ng-change="hideValue()"/>

</div>
```

> But you can't retain the old value because of the `two way binding`. So you may need to write some logic with temp variable.

Comment: I dont want to hide 1 it should be -1

Comment: Check it now @user9130953

Comment: still it is not hiding the value  when the text box contains the value of -1 then it should hide

Comment: @user9130953 You should assign the cosole value to your model. Ok please check my updated answer. :)

Comment: @RameshRajendran can you please create chat box for a min

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam why?

Comment: why $scope.realModel=""; is always making empty, it may cause loosing my values

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam Nope. It was initialize that object at first time only.

Comment: @user9130953 Please take a look at my answer. I hope this solution needed for you.

Comment: can we write reusable hideValue function for multiple text boxes

Comment: @RameshRajendran what do you mean by retain the old value

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam #User9130953 Am little bit a confusion. Who is the real OP?

Comment: @user9130953 Yes. You need to pass the ng-model property to that function. You can override that property by `Two way Binding`

Comment: Please merge your accounts. don't use duplicated users @user9130953

Comment: sure, can I remove that initialization of `$scope.realModel="";` at the controller level, as it causes many problems in my application

Comment: @user9130953 Sure. You can remove that. I also update it in my answer.

Comment: @RameshRajendran will my ng-model contains that negative value?

Comment: I gave two snippets. You can check those snippets for `-1` and all negative value like `-1` ,`-2`,`-3`..etc.

Comment: what I mean is if I get -1 in my text box then the value should hide and the ng-model should contain that value

Comment: @user9130953 That is not possible.  Please take a look this https://www.sitepoint.com/two-way-data-binding-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a solution you are looking for. But, it's a hack that looks like what you want. Essentially you change CSS and therefore hide the negative values with `ng-style`. Here is a simple demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myModule">
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-change="check()" ng-style="{color: myColor}"/>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);
module.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = '2';
  $scope.myColor = "black";
  $scope.check = function(){
    if($scope.model<0){
     $scope.myColor = "white";
    }else{
     $scope.myColor = "black";
    }
  }
}]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The solution you are looking for would include deletion and saving of numbers with a lot of complicated logic. You would need to save the value with `angular.copy($scope.model)` **iff** it's `-1`, and clear the current model, until a positive number shows up. To re-use a saved value, simply refer to its copy and not the actual model.

Here is my attempt at this complicated version:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-change="check()" />
      <br>{{model}}
      <br>{{copy}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var module = angular.module("myModule", []);

    module.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.model = '2';
      $scope.myColor = "black";
      $scope.check = function() {
        $scope.save($scope.model);
        if ($scope.model < 0) {
          $scope.model = "";
        }
      }
      $scope.save = function(val) {
        $scope.copy = angular.copy(val);
      }
    }]);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @RameshRajendran Yes, everything works for me. Here are the alternative JSFiddle versions: [hiding with CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/1xjzo5rc/), and [making a copy](https://jsfiddle.net/mwv28fc4/)

Comment: But the value didn't hide in the textbox.

Comment: @RameshRajendran in the first example it's hidden as the text has the same colour as the input field. In the second example it's completely removed (but still saved as a copy), so you can type another number to replace it

Comment: Still i can see -1 in the text box. OP want to hide it in the textbox.

Comment: @RameshRajendran that's what the second example is for. (Also you shouldn't be able to see it because the background and text colours are both white)

Comment: The OP want `when I type -1 then the value should hide in the text box`. Please take a look at the comments under my answer.

Comment: "hide **in** the text box" literally means that the value should be there, but not visible to a human eye (1st example). Figuratively speaking, the value should not be present and therefore can be removed (2nd example). The ultimate goal was to not display it, **but** still use the model value, i.e. _save_ it. In my 1st example it is saved in `$scope.model`, in the 2nd, only the copy of it should be used - `$scope.copy` since the original model was removed from DOM

Answer (score 0):

You can use *$scope.$watch('model', function(){})* or *ng-change="funciton()"* to check value after editing ng-model!